# Undefined symbols for architecture in static library (OGDF)

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, undefined-symbol, ogdf

I'm using Xcode to add [OGDF](http://www.ogdf.net/) to my C++ project. It's a static .a library, and after compiling it from sources, i've successfully add it to compile sources, set the right search paths, and everything goes right until i include for, example,`"ogdf/basic/Graph.h"`.
When i try to build with this include, linker gives me errors on the library inner files, saying there's no standart functions, like `"std::cout",` or `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)`.

It looks like this:
[image]
It's strange, since i believe such functions exists and i don't believe that OGDF developers have any mistakes in their code.
So what in fact could cause this errors?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling & linking your code as C++ and not C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to compile you code with CLang? Try to switch to GCC. I think version of you lib is GCC-specific.

Comment: Thank you, that was the thing)